# Mysql combining update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
mysql_query("UPDATE rekod SET ns = '1' WHERE zone ='255' AND data ='$id1'");
mysql_query("UPDATE rekod SET ns = '1' WHERE zone ='255' AND data ='$id2'");
```

Instead of running the query twice is there a way I can update just once? There difference is only the data value. Help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"UPDATE rekod SET ns = '1' WHERE zone ='255' AND data IN('$id1','$id2')"
```

or

```
"UPDATE rekod SET ns = '1' WHERE zone ='255' AND (data='$id1' OR data='$id2')"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an OR statement like so:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE rekod SET ns = '1' WHERE zone ='255' AND (data ='$id1' OR data = '$id2')");
```